# reduce output must shrink more rapidly, on adding new document

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I have couple of documents in couchdb, each having a cId field, such as -

```
{
   "_id": "ccf8a36e55913b7cf5b015d6c50009f7",
   "_rev": "8-586130996ad60ccef54775c51599e73f",
   "cId": 1,
   "Status": true
}
```

I have a simple view, which tries to return max of cId with map and reduce functions as follows -

Map

```
function(doc) {
   emit(null, doc.cId);
}
```

Reduce

```
function(key, values, rereduce){

 return Math.max.apply(null, values);
}
```

This works fine (output is 1) until I add one more document with cId = 2 in db. I am expecting output as 2 but it starts giving error as "Reduce output must shrink more rapidly". When I delete this document things are back to normal again. What can be the issue here? Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Note: There are more views in db, which perform different role and few return json as well. They also start failing on this change.

Comment: I would suggest to open a new question for the problem with the map and reduce functions from Edit1. It is quite different from the original question, and there are some issues, e.g. you should not emit the whole doc in the view's map function.

Comment: Posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544175/reduce-output-must-shrink-more-rapidly-reducing-to-a-list-of-documents

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the built-in `_stats`[reduce function](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions), in order to get the maximum value. It is returned in the "max" field.

Comment: I have other views as well which return json. They throw the same error.

Comment: Could you post the map and reduce functions?

Comment: Map/reduce functions are very complex. In essence, it will output a subset of documents based on few conditions. Say, there are documents with cId = 1,2,3,4,5,6 then output can be documents with cId = 1,4,5,6

Comment: Did I understand correctly, that your view emits a value that is an object (json, subset of document)? Does the reduce function return a scalar value or an object, too?

Comment: It returns an array of json documents.

Comment: That's probably the issue. Your reduce function should return a single scalar value or a small fixed-sized object or array with a fixed number of scalar values of small sizes (see http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/couchapp/views/intro.html#lessons-learned).

Comment: I am new to couchdb. Can you explain what is the limit here for "small fixed size object"? Why does my function work when it reduces to array containing 1 object out of 2 and fails if it has to reduce to array of 1 objects out of 3?

Comment: Another question is that how do I achieve what I mentioned. Basically filter out few documents and create return an array of filtered documents?

Comment: Regarding the limit for the "small fixed size object", I don't know if there is a definite answer. I guess it's around five fields, because the buil-in _stats reduce function return on object like this: `{"sum":2,"count":2,"min":1,"max":1,"sumsqr":2}`

Comment: Regarding what you want to achieve, it is hard to give advice without seeing the actual code. I guess you could filter the view based on its keys.

Comment: I have updated my question to give idea on map and reduce I am using.