# Reduce output must shrink more rapidly -- Reducing to a list of documents

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I have a few documents in my couch db with json as below. The cId will change for each. And I have created a view with map/reduce function to filter out few documents and return a list of json documents.

Document structure -

```
{
  "_id": "ccf8a36e55913b7cf5b015d6c50009f7",
  "_rev": "8-586130996ad60ccef54775c51599e73f",
  "cId": 1,
  "Status": true
}
```

Here is the sample map:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.Key && doc.Value && doc.Status == true)
      emit(null, doc);
}
```

Here is the sample reduce:

```
function(key, values, rereduce){

var kv = [];

values.forEach(function(value){
   if(value.cId != <some_val>){
       kv.push({"k": value.cId, "v" : value});  
   }
});          

return kv;
}
```

If there are two documents and reduce output has list containing 1 document, this works fine. But if I add one more document (with cId = 2), it throws the errors - "reduce output must shrink more rapidly". Why is this caused? And how can I achieve what I intend to do?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the error is, that the reduce function does not actually reduce anything (it rather is collecting objects). The [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/couchapp/views/intro.html#reduce-rereduce) mentions this:

> The way the B-tree storage works means that if you don’t actually
>   reduce your data in the reduce function, you end up having CouchDB
>   copy huge amounts of data around that grow linearly, if not faster
>   with the number of rows in your view.
>
> CouchDB will be able to compute the final result, but only for views
>   with a few rows. Anything larger will experience a ridiculously slow
>   view build time. To help with that, CouchDB since version 0.10.0 will
>   throw an error if your reduce function does not reduce its input
>   values.

It is unclear to me, what you intend to achieve.
Do you want to retrieve a list of docs based on certain criteria? In this case, a view without reduce should suffice.

Edit: If the desired result depends on a value stored in a certain document, then CouchDB has a feature called **[list](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/couchapp/ddocs.html#list-functions)**. It is a design function, that provides access to all docs of a given view, if you pass include_docs=true.

A list URL follow this pattern:

> /db/_design/foo/_list/list-name/view-name

Like views, lists are defined in a design document:

```
{
  "_id" : "_design/foo",
  "lists" : {
    "bar" : "function(head, req) { 
       var row;
       while (row = getRow()) {
         if (row.doc._id === 'baz') // Do stuff based on a certain doc
       } 
    }"
  },
  ... // views and other design functions
}
```

Comment: You are correct. I am trying to filter the list based on certain criteria. The problem is that that criteria is also present in one of the documents in the db. So, I need that as well in the same group so I can apply the logic. The map will treat all documents separately.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it.

Comment: How do we define lists? In futon, you can only define temporary views.

Comment: Views, lists, etc. are defined in design documents, see http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/. The example above shows a design doc with an id of "_design/foo". When you save a temporary view in futon, it will add it to a design doc.

Comment: I guess we need to edit the json itself. There is no proper way to add a list to a design document. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, bacsically the JavaScript goes into the JSON. There are also tools to make it more  manageable, like kanso or couchapp (https://couchapp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/couchapp/gettingstarted.html)

Comment: Ok. I made the changes and I am able to get desired results from by hitting the url. One thing though - LoveSeat throws null reference exception on querying the data -                 IListResult ilr = client.GetDatabase("mydb").List("myfilter", "myview" null, "mydesign"); This works for .View.